# Result enum overridden by other library

Tags: swift, error-handling, enums

I am trying to use the Result enum from Swift. But it seems to be overridden by a pod that I am using (Auth0).

The pod has a similar Enum Result. Something like this

```
public enum Result<T> {
    case success(result: T)
    case failure(error: Error)
}
```

How do I use the one provided by **Swift.Results** and not this one. Since it forces me to use the one from Auth0.

EDIT:
More on the error
When I try to set the return type of my function as `Result<String,Error>` it gives me the error `Generic type 'Result' specialized with too many type parameters (got 2, but expected 1)`

Comment: `it forces me to use the one from Auth0` — can you expand on this? When, how and where it forces you to do it?

Comment: its the same enum that swift provide... whats the issue ?

Comment: Try `Swift.Result<String,Error>` to override it

Comment: Please add your code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a specific definition, you need to declare it specifically, i.e:

```swift
    var result: Swift.Result<String, Error> = .success("Test")
```

OAuth overrides it so it only takes 1 value, hence the error, you can use the OAuth one like

```swift
    var result: Result<String> = .success("Test")
```

Comment: Yup, had tried that but for some reason it wasn't compiling before. Now that I try it again it does. XCode is strange sometimes. Thanks for the tip :-)